# re.search and urlopen in Python

Tags: python, regex, urllib

I have this script :

```
for url in urls:
    u = urlopen(url).read
    owner_id = re.search(r'ownerId: ([1-9]+)?,', u).group(1)
    id = re.search(r'id: ([1-9]+)?,', u).group(1)

    print(owner_id)
    print(id)
```

url is a list of urls

The script returns me "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"
Do you have an idea how to fix that ?

Comment: You should **call** with `read()` not `read` itself.

Comment: I fixed it but the same error remains

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of Python your using (below is for v3+, for v2, replace urllib with urllib2).

need to import urllib and beautiful soup

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "url address"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```